# Custom Macro not working in Different Excel Files

Tags: excel, vba

So I created this macro (DeleteOldData) in Excel that expedites some data editing for multiple datasheets within a file. The purpose of the macro is to simply delete old data based on an indicated date in cell 'D3'. This code works when I first create the macro in an excel file and run it. I tried saving the macro as an .xlam (Add-In) file so other worksheets can also utilize this macro and save me some time. However, when I add this macro to other worksheets, the code runs, but reads the indicated date as a default 12:00 AM. The following was printed when debugging when the indicated date was 4/25/2023.

> Start date entered: 12:00:00 AM

It works properly for the original excel worksheet the macro was created in, but not other worksheets. My suspicion is it has something to do with the filetype. I saved it from the workbook location -- not the VBA editor window as it had no .xlam option. What could be causing this issue and how do I resolve it so I may use this add-in in other worksheets?
This is the code I used:

```
Sub DeleteOldData()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim firstStartDate As Date
    Dim updatedWorksheets As String
    
    ' Set the workbook object to the current workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Get the start date from the first worksheet
    firstStartDate = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("D3").Value
    
    ' Loop through all the worksheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        startDate = firstStartDate
        Debug.Print "Start date entered: " & startDate
            
        ' Find the first row with a date greater than or equal to the start date
        Set rng = ws.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=startDate, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True)
        ' If the start date is not found, exit the sub
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Start date not found in Timestamp column"
            Exit Sub
        End If
            
        ' Find the last row of data
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
        ' Delete rows from the first row up to but not including the start date row
        If rng.Row > 2 And rng.Row <= lastRow Then 'skip the header row and make sure it's not the last row
            ws.Range("A2:C" & rng.Row - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp 'Delete only columns A-C and shift remaining cells up
        End If
            
        ' Shift the remaining data up
        ws.Range("A2:C" & lastRow - rng.Row + 1).Cut Destination:=ws.Range("A2")
            
        ' Autofit the columns to adjust for the new data
        ws.Columns("A:C").AutoFit
        
        ' Add the name of the updated worksheet to the list
        updatedWorksheets = updatedWorksheets & ws.Name & ", "
    
    Next ws
    ' Display a message box listing the updated worksheets
    If Len(updatedWorksheets) > 0 Then
        updatedWorksheets = Left(updatedWorksheets, Len(updatedWorksheets) - 2) ' Remove the last comma and space
        MsgBox "Data updated successfully on the following worksheets: " & updatedWorksheets & "!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No worksheets were updated."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thisworkbook refers to the workbook containing the running VBA code; i.e. your add-in. You might like to try using Application.ActiveWorkBook (or ActiveWorksheet) to get the D3 value.

Comment: I think this is the fix I was looking for. Other files can now run the macro correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems that the referred cell value is 0, and in Format Cells, Number is General .
In this case the Debug.Print of the cell give the 0 date in the format of the system's default date/time format.
Add to the print line

```
 Debug.Print "Start date entered: " & startDate , CDbl(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("D3"))
```

If the printed value is 0, that is the cause. It should be 45041 in your example.

Another idea:
Select the modul of your macro, Export it, then Import to the workbook where the data are. These commands (Export,Import) are under Files.

Answer (score 0):

`Thisworkbook` refers to the workbook containing the running VBA code; i.e. your add-in. To refer to the 'client' Wrokbook you might like to use Application.ActiveWorkBook (or ActiveWorksheet) to reference ranges on it.